# Updating dependency library versions in all poms

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a project with a top level pom, and many sub modules with their own pom files.

```
project_top
pom.xml
|->project_shr
   |->pom.xml
|->project_web
   |->pom.xml
...etc
```

I'm trying to update some dependencies to safer versions, but there might be multiple declarations of the jar in multiple poms, and some pom files may not have that jar as a dependency.  I'm wondering if there is a simple way to quickly update a jar version across an entire project, whether it's a Maven solution, IDE (I'm using IntelliJ), or anything else.  While I can scrape the entire project for the dependencies, it would take me hours.

Comment: Define the dependency in dependendencyManagement in your root pom (which defines the version of your dependency) and where you use it just define the dependency but without version...

Comment: @khmarbaise Let me try that

Comment: @khmarbaise While this is certainly a great solution for new projects, it still leads me down the road of "Go through every pom declaration of a jar and update the version".  Going forward this will be perfect project management, but I'm looking for something I can do quickly

Comment: You could use your IDE but in the end there is only one way to do it. You need to refactor your pom's as you refactor your code ...